# How to rearrange a tibble by rownames

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

Traditional dataframes support rearrangement of rows by rownames:

```
> df <- data.frame(c1 = letters[1:3], c2 = 1:3, row.names = paste0("x", 1:3))
> df
   c1 c2
x1  a  1
x2  b  2
x3  c  3

#' If we want, say, row "x3" and "x1":
> df[c("x3", "x1"), ]
   c1 c2
x3  c  3
x1  a  1
```

When it comes to tibble, since it drops the concept of rownames, I wonder what the standard way is to achieve similar goal.

```
> tb <- as_tibble(rownames_to_column(df))
> tb
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  rowname c1       c2
  <chr>   <fct> <int>
1 x1      a         1
2 x2      b         2
3 x3      c         3
> ?
```

Thanks.

### Update

I can come up with the following solution:

```
> tb[match(c("x3", "x1"), tb[["rowname"]]), ]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  rowname c1       c2
  <chr>   <fct> <int>
1 x3      c         3
2 x1      a         1
```

But it seems clumsy. Does anyone have better idea?

### Update 2

In a more generalized sense, my question can be rephrased as: by the syntax of `tidyverse`, what is the most neat and quick equivalent to

```
df[c("x3", "x1"), ]
```

that is, subsetting and rearranging rows of a dataframe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...once you convert it to a regular column you can rearrange or subset based on the values in that column just like any other.

Comment: Call `arrange` to arrange by the `rowname` column? Or is something more complicated happening & I'm missing it?

Comment: I still don't understand why you aren't just using `filter()` like you would with any other variable if you're already using tibbles.

Comment: @joran, AFAIK, it seems that `filter` does not keep the results in specified order...

Comment: No, there's a separate command for that, `arrange`.

Comment: Hi @camille @joran, current problem is that `arrange` can sort a column (in either increasing or decreasing order), but not arrange it in an arbitrary order (e.g. "x3", "x1").

Comment: If you're trying to get rows by position, use `dplyr::slice`. Or `filter` with `%in%`

Comment: Thanks @camille, but how to get position with `dplyr` in the first place?

Comment: If you wanted rows 3 and 1 of `df`, it's `slice(df, c(3, 1))`. Or filter by the rowname column

Comment: Sorry @camille, to use `slice(df, c(3, 1))` we have to know where "x3" and "x1" are, so we need to map `c("x3" , "x1")` to `c(3, 1)` first. In my worked example, I used `match`, and hoped somebody could show me something better. On the other hand, `filter(rowname %in% c("x3", "x1"))` as @joshpk showed in the answer, did not keep the particular order ("x3" first, then "x1"). To do so, @joshpk used an ingenious trick with an additional `arrange` plus an ordered factor, and again, I wanted to see if any other elegant alternatives. In summary, I'm afraid, neither of your reply hits my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As joran described, you can use filter to select rows of interest and then to arrange a tibble in a specific order, manually defined, you can use `arrange` with `factor`:

```
tibble(rowname = paste0("x", 1:3), c1 = letters[1:3], c2 = 1:3) %>%
  filter(rowname %in% c("x3", "x1")) %>%
  arrange(factor(rowname, levels = c("x3", "x1")))
```